# Native API not changing in html and don't work with livereload

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, observable, batterylevel

i'm connecting Ionic cordova to my physical device with USB and command : `ionic cordova run android --livereload.`

Thats the using this code to get the BatteryStatus:

```js
export class HomePage {
  batterystatus$: number;
  subscription : any;
  constructor(private batteryStatus: BatteryStatus, public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    alert('ionViewDidLoad BatteryStatus');
    // watch change in battery status
    this.subscription = this.batteryStatus.onChange().subscribe(
      (status: BatteryStatusResponse) => {
        this.batterystatus$ = status.level;
        console.log(status.level, status.isPlugged);
      }
    );

    // stop watch

  }
  ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>
  {{subscription}}
  {{ batterystatus$}}
  bbbbbb
  <p>
    This starter project comes with simple tabs-based layout for apps
    that are going to primarily use a Tabbed UI.
  </p>
  <p>
    Take a look at the <code>src/pages/</code> directory to add or change tabs,
    update any existing page or create new pages.
  </p>
</ion-content>
```

**The problem:** When i start the app by the first time, it shows the current BatteryLevel on my view. As livereload is activated when i make a change to de code it "Builds..." the app with my change, **but then the current BatteryLevel don't appear anymore**.

**The Other Problem:** When i leave the app with the first start, **without making changes to the code so the app don't build** it doesn't send changes changes of **the battery level** to the **variable**, it **keeps static**.